# Can an object have multiple rigid body constraints?

Tags: rigid-body-simulation

I want to simulate the motion of an artist's brush. A spine of pivot-constrained spheres will collide with a z-plane, which represents the canvas. To mimic the elastic properties of a bristle I need to constrain alternate spheres with rigid-body generic springs. It appears Blender will only allow one rigid-body constraint per object. Using various combinations of non-physics constraints and parenting causes erratic motion in the simulation.